# R: how to sum columns grouped by a factor?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

If I have a table like this:

```
user,v1,v2,v3
a,1,0,0
a,1,0,1
b,1,0,0
b,2,0,3
c,1,1,1
```

How to I turn it into this?

```
user,v1,v2,v3
a,2,0,1
b,3,0,3
c,1,1,1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` for this:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(
  user = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"),
  v1   = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1),
  v2   = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  v3   = c(0, 1, 0, 3, 1))

group_by(df, user) %>% 
summarize(v1_sum = sum(v1),
          v2_sum = sum(v2),
          v3_sum = sum(v3))
```

If you're not familiar with the `%>%` notation, it is basically like piping from bash. It takes the output from `group_by()` and puts it into `summarize()`. The same thing would be accomplished this way:

```
by_user = group_by(df, user)
df_summarized = summarize(by_user, 
                          v1_sum = sum(v1),
                          v2_sum = sum(v2),
                          v3_sum = sum(v3))
```

Comment: works well for integers and round numeric, but for numeric with decimals, it rounds the number (depending on which RStudio version is used e.g. with v1.2.5042 decimals are gone, eventhough getOption("digits")=7). The workaround for this is to pipe %>% as.data.frame() after it. Below solution with aggregate() keeps decimals by default, and is way more self-descriptive and intuitive, although a bit slower.

Comment: @alp the decimals aren't gone, but when using dplyr the output is a "tibble" object, which is a data.frame with some additional properties, one of which is that they don't show the decimals when printing if the values are large enough. So the values are still there, but when printed in the screen they are not shown. By piping the output to "as.data.frame()" you convert it back to a data.frame which does print decimals by default.

Answer (score 5):

In base R,

```
D <- matrix(c(1, 0, 0,
              1, 0, 1,
              1, 0, 0,
              2, 0, 3,
              1, 1, 1),
            ncol=3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(1:5, c("v1", "v2", "v3")))
D <- data.frame(user=c("a", "a", "b", "b", "c"), D)
aggregate(. ~ user, D, sum)
```

Returns

```
> aggregate(. ~ user, D, sum)
  user v1 v2 v3
1    a  2  0  1
2    b  3  0  3
3    c  1  1  1
```