# colSums and group by

Tags: r, aggregation

I have the following table below:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| Condition | LabelA | LabelB | LabelC |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
| TRUE      |      1 |      1 |      0 |
| TRUE      |      0 |      1 |      0 |
| FALSE     |      0 |      1 |      1 |
| FALSE     |      1 |      0 |      1 |
| TRUE      |      1 |      1 |      0 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Which I'd like to summarise (sum aggregation) into:

```
+--------+------+-------+
| Labels | TRUE | FALSE |
+--------+------+-------+
| LabelA |    2 |     1 |
| LabelB |    3 |     1 |
| LabelC |    0 |     2 |
+--------+------+-------+
```

I can do this by creating two sub tables on whether `Condition == TRUE` and then `colSums` that table, however I suspect there is a more elegant way to keep everything into one table (shown above).

This differs from [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32545710/r-how-to-sum-columns-grouped-by-a-factor) because the column names (LabelA, LabelB, LabelC) become rows.

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df %>% gather(key=Labels, value, -Condition) %>% group_by(Condition, Labels) %>% summarise(sum=sum(value)) %>% spread(Condition, sum)`

Comment: `aggregate(.~Condition, df, sum)`